# Keyboard Listener for Mac using Python

Tags: python, macos, keyboard

I have tried all the codes for the keyboard listener. I had come across a post which said that Mac blocks the system to listen to the keyboard presses. I am using python. I am also using pynput as the library. How can I make Mac listen to my key presses? It only listens to special keys like 'Shift', 'Alt' and 'Command'.

Comment: are you asking how to build a keylogger for mac ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389665/python-capture-keystrokes-values-in-text-file-on-os-x

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't a bug in pynput but a security feature of os x. You have to run Python as root to get around it.

```
sudo python3 app.py
```

If you don't want to keep using sudo the permanent fix is to go into the Security and Privacy preferences and add Python to the Accessibility tab.

Comment: https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/blob/master/docs/limitations.rst

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> Use pynput.keyboard.Listener like this:
>
> ```
> from pynput import keyboard
>
> def on_press(key):
>     try:
>         print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(
>             key.char))
>     except AttributeError:
>         print('special key {0} pressed'.format(
>             key))
>
> def on_release(key):
>     print('{0} released'.format(
>         key))
>     if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
>         # Stop listener
>         return False
>
> # Collect events until released
> with keyboard.Listener(
>         on_press=on_press,
>         on_release=on_release) as listener:
>     listener.join()
> ```
>
> A keyboard listener is a threading.Thread, and all callbacks will be
>   invoked from the thread.
>
> Call pynput.keyboard.Listener.stop from anywhere, raise StopException
>   or return False from a callback to stop the listener.
>
> The key parameter passed to callbacks is a pynput.keyboard.Key, for
>   special keys, a pynput.keyboard.KeyCode for normal alphanumeric keys,
>   or just None for unknown keys.

Comment: Will not be able to listen to alphanumeric keys in Mac.

Comment: Why will it not be able to listen to alphanumeric keys?